# Get hyperlink from a cell in google Sheet api V4

Tags: python, google-sheets

I want to get the hyperlink of a cell (A1, for example) in Python. I have this code so far. Thanks

```
properties = {
    "requests": [
    {
        "cell": {
            "HyperlinkDisplayType": "LINKED"
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.HyperlinkDisplayType"
    }

    ]
    }

result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=rangeName, body=properties).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

Comment: You may want to put more details here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a hyperlink using Google Sheets API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632838/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-using-google-sheets-api)

Answer (score 9):

How about using [`sheets.spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)? This sample script supposes that `service` of your script has already been able to be used for `spreadsheets().values().get()`.

#### Sample script :

```
spreadsheetId = '### Spreadsheet ID ###'
range = ['sheet1!A1:A1'] # This is a sample.
result = service.spreadsheets().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
    ranges=range,
    fields="sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink"
).execute()
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: This works for me, question, where can I find documentation on the `fields` parameter? It is not listed in the API link

Comment: @rinkert Unfortunately, in the current stage, I cannot find the detail document about `fields` parameter. In the current stage, it seems that the simple document like https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get is seen. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: ah don't worry about it, your solution did work, and my problem is solved, so thx!

Comment: @rinkert Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether this can be achieved soon, I would like to propose to add the detail document about how to use `fields` for Google APIs.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to me like this is the only way to actually get the link info (address as well as display text):

```
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=range_name, 
        valueRenderOption='FORMULA').execute()
values = results.get('values', [])
```

This returns the raw content of the cells which for hyperlinks look like this for each cell:

```
'=HYPERLINK("sample-link","http://www.sample.com")'
```

For my use I've parsed it with the following simple regex:

```
r'=HYPERLINK\("(.*?)","(.*?)"\)'
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. I don't really understand how to do the regex thing you said as I've never really worked with strings. How does this work?

Comment: Let me put that more clearly. How would I turn the string with the raw content into a string with the link and a string with the content of the cell?

Comment: @Gijsfwb Hi, first if you're not familiar with regex you should read up on it (a good starting point is the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Second, here's a quick example of usage: https://ideone.com/4FKVsC

Answer (score 0):

You can check the hyperlink if you add at the end:

> print (values[0])

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry insufficient my answer.

Comment: Don't worry. Your code might works but I couldn't find how to do that exactly. Than anyway

Comment: Thank you. Is the script in my answer not working for your environment? Can I see your whole script? If you can do, please add it to your question. Of course, please remove your personal information.