# How to add a hyperlink using Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a python script to add hyperlinks to a google sheet. I'm using the google api for this. From searching, I've gathered that I need pass the rest api a "=HYPERLINK()" type of message.

From documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ExtendedValue.FIELDS.formula_value

```
{
  // Union field value can be only one of the following:
  "numberValue": number,
  "stringValue": string,
  "boolValue": boolean,
  "formulaValue": string,
  "errorValue": {
    object(ErrorValue)
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field value.
}
```

It looks like I should be using the 'formulaValue' property.

Edit:
I've attempted to use the [UpdateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest) request

Edit: Solution below.

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out:

```
def addHyperlink(self, hyperlink, text, sheetId, rowIndex, colIndex):
    requests = []
    requests.append({
        "updateCells": {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "values": [{
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "formulaValue":"=HYPERLINK({},{})".format(hyperlink, text) 
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ],
            "fields": "userEnteredValue",
            "start": {
                "sheetId": sheetId,
                "rowIndex": rowIndex,
                "columnIndex": colIndex
            }
        }})
    body = {
        "requests": requests
    }
    request = self.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheetId, body=body)
    return request.execute()
```

Comment: I'm using this piece of code https://jsfiddle.net/vikashrajgupta/oy9ujkLb/

And wanted to insert an HTML text as a hyperlink in the Google sheet.
I'm new in this so need help, possible to add?

Answer (score -1):

links not worked!!! But add like note)

```
def addHyperlink(self, uri_1, summa_, sheetId, rowIndex, colIndex):
    requests = []
    requests.append({
        "updateCells": {
            "rows": [{
                "values": [{
                    'userEnteredValue': {'numberValue': float(summa_)}, #
                    'effectiveValue': {'numberValue': float(summa_)},
                    'formattedValue': "р."+summa_,
                    'userEnteredFormat': {
                        'numberFormat': {'type': 'NUMBER', 'pattern': '[$р.-419]#,##0.00'},
                        'backgroundColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 1, 'blue': 0.6}, 'borders': {
                            'top': {
                                'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1, 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {}}},
                            'bottom': {
                                'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1, 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {}}},
                            'left': {
                                'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1, 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {}}},
                            'right': {
                                'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1, 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {}}}},
                        'horizontalAlignment': 'RIGHT', 'verticalAlignment': 'BOTTOM',
                        'textFormat': {
                            'foregroundColor': {'red': 0.06666667, 'green': 0.33333334, 'blue': 0.8},
                            'fontFamily': 'Arial', 'underline': True,
                            'foregroundColorStyle': {'rgbColor': {'red': 0.06666667, 'green': 0.33333334, 'blue': 0.8}},
                            'link': {'uri': uri_1}
                        },
                        'hyperlinkDisplayType': 'LINKED','backgroundColorStyle': {'rgbColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 1, 'blue': 0.6}}
                    }
                    ,                            'hyperlink': uri_1 , 'note': uri_1,
                }
                ]
            }], "fields": '*', "start": {
                "sheetId": sheetId, "rowIndex": rowIndex, "columnIndex": colIndex}}})
    body = {
        "requests": requests}
    request = self.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheetId, body=body)
    return request.execute()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).