# Getting hyperlink from cell in google sheets API python

Tags: python, google-sheets, discord.py, google-sheets-api

I'm quite new to python and to using the google sheets API. I saw a different thread with about the same question, and the answer seems like it should work for my purpose, but it doesn't. I'm working on a discord bot that grabs information from a google sheets document, and I'm trying to make a command that takes a hyperlink from a specific cell and posts it in discord. My code is as follows:

```
# Call the Sheets API
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        #######################################################################
        sheetName = title
        result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='SpreadsheetId',
                                    range=sheetName).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])
        resultLink = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='SpreadsheetId',
                                    range=sheetName,fields="sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink").execute()
        valuesLink = resultLink.get('values', [])
```

I'm using the values array to find the cell I'm looking for, and I don't think that's the problem.

The code I'm using for resultLink is copied from the other question I found, but the console gives an error and I don't quite see what's wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Other question thread: [Get hyperlink from a cell in google Sheet api V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879715/get-hyperlink-from-a-cell-in-google-sheet-api-v4)

Comment: What error do you see? Is the issue related to getting the hyperlink, or posting it to Discord?

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And, from your script, I would like to modify from `valuesLink = resultLink.get('values', [])` to `valuesLink = [[c.get('hyperlink', []) for c in r.get('values', [])] for r in resultLink['sheets'][0]['data'][0].get('rowData', [])]`? Because in the case of the response value from `sheet.values().get()`, `resultLink.get('values', [])` returns `[]`. But I cannot understand about your actual cells including the hyperlinks. So if this was not the direct solution, I apologize again.

Comment: @Jescanellas the error is almost certainly related to not getting the hyperlink, but I don't get a specific error

Comment: @Tanaike thank you! I'll try that now. does a cell without a hyperlink return an empty array or an empty string?

Comment: Okay it seems like the ```resultLink = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='SpreadsheetId',
                                    range=sheetName,fields="sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink").execute()``` gives an error, so something it that line doesn't work

Comment: Which error does it show?