# Google sheets api- Python/Django, receive a hidden links from cells

Tags: python, django, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-api

[Screenshot of sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG0LS.png)

Hi, I have a problem with parsing a link from google sheets cells. I need to create a parser that will parse sheets with links in cells.

Here is a piece of code:

```
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,range='Some Table!A2:J28',valueRenderOption='FORMULA').execute()
```

But I received only the name from the cell. How can I receive a hidden link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get hyperlink from a cell in google Sheet api V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879715/get-hyperlink-from-a-cell-in-google-sheet-api-v4)

Comment: Thank you @Kessy for your answer. I have tried this answer, but it is not work in my case.

Comment: Can you share more information on it? I have tried the answer from that post on a sheet of my own and it worked. Why is it not working for you?

Comment: @Kessy. I've received the csv file but instead of hidden links under the names there are only pure names without links.

Comment: What do you mean by that? If there are no links, what links are you trying to get? Apologies if I am misunderstanding it.